# Global sections of holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, and $\mathbb{L}\rightarrow X$ a holomorphic line bundle over $X.$

Can we always find global sections of $\mathbb{L}$?
(other from the one that's identically zero) On a real manifold, the answer is of course yes due to the existence of partition of unity.

What about an arbitrary holomorphic vector bundle $\mathbb{E}\rightarrow X$ of rank $m$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No and no. This is one of the fundamental differences between holomorphic geometry and differential geometry. Of course a trivial bundle has holomorphic sections, so the simplest counterexample is the next simplest complex line bundle, the tautological bundle $L\to \mathbb{C} P^1$ whose fiber at a point $[\ell]$ is the line $\ell$ itself. (To be precise, this defines $L$ via an embedding to $\mathbb{C} P^1\times \mathbb{C}^2$.) The sections of this $L$, often notated $\mathcal{O}(-1)$, are generated by $x_0^{-1}$ and $x_1^{-1}$. Neither of these is globally defined, and indeed $L$ has no global sections at all.

Comment: How about non-trivial meromorphic sections?