# Global sections of vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

There are a few posts that are related to what I'm asking (e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200344/global-sections-of-holomorphic-vector-bundles?rq=1))  but aren't precisely what I had in mind. The question is fairly basic but is one that confuses me:

Does a  holomorphic vector bundle $V$ over a complex manifold $X$ admit a zero section? If so, why is $H^0(X, V) = 0$ (for bundles in which the structure group acts non-trivially)? I'm sure there's a fairly straightforward answer to this but I'm not so well-informed on the subject.

Comment: All vector bundles have zero sections. This of course does not necessarily mean $H^0(X,V)=0$, it may have non-zero sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's always a zero section. $H^0(X,V)$ is the vector space of sections. Writing $H^0(X,V) = 0$ means that it is the zero vector space, which contains exactly one element, namely the zero section.

Comment: I think I understand now -  because it is a single value (0) instead of, say, $\mathbb{R}$, it is zero-dimensional instead of being one-dimensional, correct? That is, $H^0(X, V) = 0 \rightarrow  h^0(X, V) = 0 $ but $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = \mathbb{R} \rightarrow h^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)) =1$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct